# Is there a closed mailing group service?

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for a service that would allow me to

- create private/closed mailing list
- create managers for that list
- add new user on their behalf
- allow users to manage their membership

It is for our [floorball team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floorball) communication. So it is non-profit usage but needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Yahoo Groups should do everything that you want.  I have run private groups with multiple moderators, and users can add or remove themselves as they see fit.

Comment: Looks like all members must have Yahoo ID, doesn't it. Can I create sub groups?

Comment: The members don't need to have Yahoo IDs if an admin adds them to the group, but then I'm not sure if they can manage their own group settings.  Not sure what you mean by a sub group?

Comment: Let's say that the group have 23 members and then I want to have sub groups where we can send emails only to males, females, people that are playing different levels of competitions etc...

Comment: No, there is no feature like that in Yahoo Groups.  It is more of a listserv, where all emails go to all members.